# iPad Pro 12" Landscape Responsive Issues

Tags: html, css, ipad, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

Just wondering if anyone has issues with the new Ipad Pro 12" for responsive. I have built an interactive site in Boostrap 3 with .JS on. When the client of mine sees the website on the iPad Pro the widths brake and there non of the animations work on the site.

talegatetheatre.co.uk

Any ideas why this is happening.

I have attached some screenshots of what it looks like on the iPad Pro landscape.
[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]
[image: Screenshot 4]

Thanks,
James

Comment: There is no screenshot :(

Comment: You might want to include some code snippets.